# How to save an image stretch/enhancement in ENVI?

Tags: remote-sensing, imagery, envi, digital-image-processing

I am using ENVI 5.3.1 and viewing a georeferenced satellite image with a linear 1% histogram stretch applied to the entire image. When exporting the image with the current histogram stretch using **File->Export View To->Image File**, the image enhancements do not remain.

I have also tried **File->Save As->Save As... (ENVI,NITF,TIFF,DTED)**. Is there a way to retain (and export) the image as stretched in the viewer into a separate TIFF file?

Answer (score -1):

You have to edit the header file of the image loaded into ENVI.
Simply Search for Header Tool in the toolbox search.